# What happens if I ffmpeg encode two times successively with the same bitrate

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encode

I have a original divx video (3500k) which I encode to h.264 in a mp4 container. I choose to encode it with 1000 k for instance so that the quality stays close to the original. What happens if I encode it then one more time with the same bitrate?  Theoretically should the quality stay the same?

```
ffmpeg -i A.divx -an -vcodec h264  -b:v 100k A.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

## The quality will not remain the same

Re-encoding with a lossy encoder will reduce the quality each time. This is called [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

> Generation loss is the loss of quality between subsequent copies or
>   transcodes of data. Anything that reduces the quality of the
>   representation when copying, and would cause further reduction in
>   quality on making a copy of the copy, can be considered a form of
>   generation loss. File size increases are a common result of generation
>   loss, as the introduction of artifacts may actually increase the
>   entropy of the data through each generation.

`ffmpeg` fully decodes the input to raw video and PCM audio no matter the input format:

```
 _______              ______________
|       |            |              |
| input |  demuxer   | encoded data |   decoder
| file  | ---------> | packets      | -----+
|_______|            |______________|      |
                                           v
                                       _________
                                      |         |
                                      | decoded |
                                      | frames  |
                                      |_________|
 ________             ______________       |
|        |           |              |      |
| output | <-------- | encoded data | <----+
| file   |   muxer   | packets      |   encoder
|________|           |______________|
```

It then encodes the raw video which includes the damaging compression artifacts from previous encoding iterations. The quality will not remain the same because the two generations are essentially completely different videos.